# Generating Samples from Customized Distribution - Stuck with Range Limitation

Tags: r, sample, quantile, probability-density, uniroot

I'm struggling to generate samples from a custom distribution defined by its CDF but facing a persistent limitation. The issue boils down to:

**Limited Range of Samples:** Despite having a theoretical range of 0 to infinity, my function only produces samples within a very narrow range, typically close to 2.5 in my case. I've tried adjusting various parameters `(phi1, gam, del)` and even expanding the search range for the `uniroot  function`, but haven't achieved the desired spread.

**Specific Function and Code:**

Here's the core function and example code for illustrative purposes:

```
sim.g <- function(n, phi1, gam, del) {
  CDF <- function(t, phi, gamma, delta) {
    return(1 - exp(-phi * t^gamma * exp(delta * t)))
  }
  quantile_function <- function(p, phi, gamma, delta) {
    f <- function(t) CDF(t, phi, gamma, delta) - p
    root <- uniroot(f, c(0, 10000))
    return(root$root)
  }
  T1 <- c(rep(0, n))
  for (i in 1:n) {
    u <- runif(1)
    T1[i] <- quantile_function(u, phi1, gam, del)
  }
  print(T1)
}
sim.g(n = 30, phi1 = 0.1, gam = 1.5, del = 4)
```

What techniques or adjustments could help overcome this range limitation and generate samples across the intended range (0 to 100 in my case)?

Any insights or guidance on tackling this challenge would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your expertise and support!

Comment: Your CDF attains a value of 0.999 at a value of t = 1.04.  So sampling values in the range 1 to 100 is almost impossible, especially with a sample size of 30.  Plot the graph and you'll see what I mean.  Since the CDF is essentially flat for most of the range you are seraching, `uniroot` is probably unreliable.

Comment: Try parameters values of phi1, gam and del closer to 0 - say 0.05.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is producing desire results for small values of parameters.